# if Kundalini is what leads to enlightenment,why do many who have reached it not become Jivanmuktis?

Tags: kundalini

Bonpos,Vajrayanists and Taoists all raise their kundalini thru Tummo practices and other means yet do not reach Hindu enlightenment.they do reach their own enlightenment but they reject an atman,they reject the Vedas,and they Reject Devi and Shiva as supreme after the fact.a Jivanmukti would be omniscient and not do this.of course,the bonpos and vajrayanists claim omniscience aswell after successful sadhana of tummo,wich elads to their enlightenment.and these are not even similar as in bonpo and Vajrana nirvanas,there is total cessation of feeling while in tantrik enlightenment there is the feeling of bliss.

the Advaita Vedantists say in responce to Tantrikas that kundalini is not conducive to enlightenment.this would make sence.unless view had something to do with it.thats what the bonpos and Vajrayanists would claim.most tantrik practices are the same in both systems but view is what brings wich result according to them.but in hindu tantrik circles it seems if shakti reaches shiva in the sahasrara then you should become a Jivanmukta.Ramakrishna even said on some stages you will find all ungodly talk horrible.yet that is not the case with these people that practice kundalini for their own enlightenment where they dont even Believe in ishvara.

because when Bonpos or Vajrayanists Practice Tummo they raise their kundalini and reach their own forms of enlightenment but not Tantrik enlightenment.

it seems to me that Kundalini is just another Energy of the body and is simply the Fire element in the body and not some shakti living in all beings.the result thereof practiced by Tantrikas is simply a Blissful clarity not unlike the result of Shamatha meditations.this is the view of former Tantrik practicioners like Sridhar Samsher J B Rana(He reached Tantrik enlightenment according to his famous Guru but left hinduism after he reached enlightenment!) .he says that Kundalini is merely a inferior shamatha meditation too.

what are your thoughts?

Comment: Advaita vedanta doesn't have concept of kundalini. Moreover you should read authentic scriptures to know about it. You can start with books by sir John woodrofe